# HP laserjet 1020 plus printer not working in Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: hplip

I have upgraded to Ubuntu 14.04. Hp Printer 1020 plus installed but device manager says not found. I cannot print. Can somebody help me out

Answer (score 9):

In fresh 16.04, Ubuntu auto-detected my HP 1020, but it did not work. I ran `hp-setup -i` (which was preinstalled), and it started working.

*Edit: works also for Ubuntu 18.04.*

Comment: Works also for Ubuntu 19.04.

Answer (score 3):

Install some required packages. By copy pasting following code into terminal.

```
sudo apt-get install hp-ppd printer-driver-hpcups printer-driver-hpijs hpijs-ppds hplip hplip-data hplip-dbg hplip-doc hplip-gui djtools
```

Now run `hp-setup` from terminal to add the printer, which will show you a gui from which you can add the printer.

This worked for me on Bodhi Linux (which is Ubuntu 14.04 based). So might work on 14.04 of Xubuntu,Kubuntu,etc.

Note:- It works nicely with KDE too.

Also see,
[Problem with printing (hplip) in Ubuntu 14.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/464651/problem-with-printing-hplip-in-ubuntu-14-04)

Answer (score 1):

Just open the software centre, search for hplip and select "show hidden technical elements (or something like that)". Install hplip and then you'll be able to easily set up your printer

Answer (score 1):

I installed hplip including the UI. Then opened hplip and pressed the "hammer" button on the toolbar for self diagnosis.

It opened a console that did all the job, I only answered some questions out there. But now it works.

Comment: Please provide more info on this answer - like how you actually installed the hplip and the UI. Some screenshots also would be better other than just '...pressed the "hammer" button on the toolbar...'.

Answer (score 0):

Try with installing HP printer drivers and config packages:

```
sudo apt-get install hp-ppd hpijs hpijs-ppds hplip hplip-cups hplip-data hplip-dbg hplip-doc hplip-gui djtools
```

Answer (score 0):

Connect your printer to your PC, and make sure to switch it on,
Then used the command :

```
hp-doctor
```

This is a very interactive/easy way to install the printer.
It also installs any missing dependencies.

Answer (score 0):

Simply open the app manager. Press the search icon. Type hplip. Select hplip. Tap install. Open it. Run the self diagnostics.