# Problem with printing (hplip) in Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, printing, hplip

Earlier when I run Ubuntu 12.04, It prompts to install printer on detecting by XTerm (It automatically download and configures hplip) and my hp-laserjet working fine on Ubuntu 12.04.

Now, I am running Ubuntu 14.04 (Installed form DVD). When I plugged printer, XTerm doesn't prompts so, **I manually configured as following**.

**1. Open printer setting. It detects my Hp Laser Jet P1007**
[image: detect]

**2. It Auto configured correctly and ask to print test page**
[image: Described][image: test-page]

**3. But It not prints test-page. Also not-printing anything and says job completed!**
[image: queue]

Though It detected & configured properly but not printing.

---

**Details from local-host**:[image: localhost]

---

How to solve It?

Comment: Try looking at the cups web interface at http://localhost:631 and making sure your printer is the default printer and is enabled.

Comment: @bain : I also added details from  localhost:631.

Comment: And this previously worked in 12.04 - exactly the same computer, printer, USB port etc.? Did you run `hp-setup` after installing 14.04?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You need to run `hp-setup` after installing Ubuntu 14.04.

`hp-setup` Installs  HPLIP  printers  and  faxes  in the CUPS spooler. Tries to automatically determine the correct PPD file to use. Allows the printing of a testpage. Performs basic fax parameter setup.

Comment: If I remember well, I tried to use `hp-setup` (amongst others) to get my HP LaserJet 1020 to reliably print in 14.04, but had to give up and buy an HP LaserJet Professional P1102, which works flawlessly. (In case someone wonders why I didn't buy the wireless model: because I don't like electromagnetic pollution.)

Comment: You may need to run `sudo apt-get install hplip-dbg hplip-gui` before running hp-setup

Answer (score 4):

Run `hp-setup`, then if the problem still persists follow these steps, too:

1. Go to http://localhost:631/, then go to "Printers", there your printer will be listed under queue name, click it.
2. Click "Administration" drop down menu
3. Select "set allowed users"
4. Type in your computer "username" and "select allow these users to print" and click "Set allowed Users".

I successfully got the printer running using these steps in Ubuntu 14.04 LTS.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem in **Ubuntu 17.04** and **Hp Laser Jet P1006** but neither installing by [localhost:631](http://localhost:631/) or setting "allowed users" nor using printers part of Ubuntu system tools helped me.

But I fixed the problem by removing printer in system tools > printers and **running `hp-setup -i`** that is an interface for "hplip".

By `hp-setup -i` setting up a new printer would be  easy and without problem. 

I added my new printer by using `hp-setup -i` steps and in final step it asked me for test print and then everything worked great.

Answer (score 0):

All drivers with ljet4 sufix should work, you just have to find the right one. This should work for other printers too. In my company I had problems until I found out that few drivers works for all printer. I wrote large text about  drivers solution [here](http://linuxibos.blogspot.ba/2013/01/driver-that-works-on-allmost-all.html). I tried it on most of Ubuntu versions.