# How do I disable usb 2.0 devices?

Tags: dual-boot, drivers, usb, hp

I have a Compaq cq5115uk dual booted Windows Vista & Ubuntu 14.04 and a HP Laserjet 1020 printer. Under Windows the printer only works if I disable the usb 2.0 devices in Windows device manager leaving only the usb 1.1 devices. Under Ubuntu the printer doesn't work. I'm guessing the problem is the same as Windows, so I'd like to know how to disable usb 2.0 under Ubuntu. Thanks

mike@mike-VC913AA-ABU-CQ5115UK:lsusb

```
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 058f:6366 Alcor Micro Corp. Multi Flash Reader
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 008 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 007 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 006 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 005 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 004 Device 002: ID 0461:0010 Primax Electronics, Ltd HP Keyboard
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 003 Device 002: ID 046d:c52f Logitech, Inc. Unifying Receiver
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
```

Comment: You mean, the printer has to set to usb1.1 manually?

Comment: Possible duplicates: http://askubuntu.com/questions/462329/hp-laserjet-1020-plus-printer-not-working-in-ubuntu-14-04 http://askubuntu.com/questions/452161/hp-laser-jet-1020-plus-installation

Comment: @markkirby Not duplicates. Your references discuss printers not being added. I added mine fine, but it didn't work once added. Except now having tried some of these solutions I've lost and can't re-add the printer.

Comment: @davidbaumann if(the printer has to be set to usb 1.1 manually == disable the usb 2.0 devices in Windows device manager leaving only the usb 1.1 devices) then yes else no

Answer (score 0):

How to disable usb 2.0 under Ubuntu?

Try with one feature in the kernel, the ability to bind and unbind drivers from devices manually from user space.

In the sysfs tree, every driver now has bind and unbind files associated with it.

In order to unbind a device from a driver, simply write the bus id of the device to the unbind file.

See more at: [Bind-Unbind](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/12005/how-to-use-linux-kernel-driver-bind-unbind-interface-for-usb-hid-devices)

Comment: Thanks. Unfortunately I've now lost the connection to the printer by using some of the other suggestions, so I have to fix that before trying your suggestion.